Ratio of parts of triangle-side divided by line connecting vertex to circumcenter
Say we have a circumscribed triangle $ABC$ with circumcenter $O$. Say also that $D$ is the intersection of the (infinite) line $AO$ with $BC$.
I've been trying to determine the ratio of $BD$ and $CD$ as a function of $\angle BAD=\alpha$ and $\angle CAD=\beta$.
This is the closest I could get, using the Law of Sines:
$$
\frac{DC}{BD}=\frac{\frac{AD\sin\left(\beta\right)}{\sin\left(\angle ACD\right)}}{\frac{AD\sin\left(\alpha\right)}{\sin\left(\angle ABD\right)}}=\frac{\sin\left(\beta\right)}{\sin\left(\alpha\right)}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\angle ABD\right)}{\sin\left(\angle ACD\right)}
$$
And after this point, each direction I had attempted to proceed through to simplify those $\angle ABD$ and $\angle ACD$ got really complicated and ugly.
What would be a friendly way to approach this problem?
Here's a sketch:


@c'estpasnormale - noted and done; thanks for the tip!

$\angle ACD=90°-\alpha$ and $\angle ABD=90°-\beta$.

@Intelligentipauca, thanks a lot for your input! Could you please give me a hint as for how to show this? I had already tried playing with the perpendicular-bisectors-intersection property of the circumcenter in order to make use of the circumcenter detail (which I so far hadn't), but failed to get anywhere with it.

The inscribed angle theorem also works when the inscribed angle has one of its sides tangent to the circle. Wikipedia states that here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Corollary but I haven't been able to find a proof in English. Here's one in French: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_l%27angle_inscrit_et_de_l%27angle_au_centre#Angle_de_la_corde_et_d'une_tangente

In other words $\angle ACB$ is the same as the angle formed by $BA$ with the tangent at $A$ (and not containing $C$). Because they are both one half of the central angle insisting on $AB$.


Note that AI is the diameter of the circumcircle, then we have:
$\angle ABC=\angle AIC= 90^o-\beta$
$\angle ACB=\angle AIB=90^o-\alpha$
You found:
$\frac{DC}{DB}=\frac{sin\beta}{sin\alpha}\cdot\frac{sin\angle ABD}{sin\angle ACD}$
So we can write:
$\frac{DC}{DB}=\frac{sin\beta}{sin\alpha}\cdot\frac{sin(90^o-\beta)}{sin(90^o-\alpha)}$
$sin(90-\alpha)=cos\alpha$
$sin(90-\beta)=cos \beta$
finally:
$\frac{DC}{DB}=\frac{sin\beta}{sin\alpha}\cdot\frac{cos \beta}{cos \alpha}=\frac{sin 2\beta}{sin 2\alpha}$

Thank you; that's awesome. It's been a good minute since I solved any geometric questions and the concept of inscribed angles absolutely bounced off my rust.
